# How to Connect a list from another Sharepoint Web Application

Tags: filter, web-application

How Could I connect a SharePoint another list which is situated in another web application? A mast get another list from another web application, and give a filter to show only this elements, which are on filter. How could I create dynamical filter ?

Comment: which version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint exposes an API, and you can find there a service for accessing lists and the list items: ListData.svc a wcf service that follows REST protocol. Here's a link with a tutorial on how to do it: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/09/get-list-items-in-sharepoint-2010/

If you are having trouble with the CAML query, use the CAML query builder from: http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/

Also Check these.

[Accessing list data between web applications](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2022/accessing-list-data-between-web-applications)

[How can we connect with another applications to sharepoint list and read it's items?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55476/how-can-we-connect-with-another-applications-to-sharepoint-list-and-read-its-it)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14e69c95-78a3-41cc-a284-77436fab095c/sharepoint-cross-webapplication-lookup-column